# Which Android library determines the application and the activity which initially launches?

Tags: java, android, netbeans-7

I am experiencing my first taste in android development. Took me sometime to get the environment set-up and to load the current project. I am reviewing the project and I'm lacking the knowledge in recognizing the basics.

I actually referred to the auto-generated AndroidManifest.xml to determine which class started the application and which one initially launches. I reviewed the files inside their respective packages and I am trying to determine which imported libraries are determining this.

For the application, I think it's pretty obvious:

```
import android.app.Application;
```

Here is a snippet of the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nlrt.sanome"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <!--
        TODO: I should look into this warning about allowing backup:

            Should explicitly set android:allowBackup to true or false (it's true by default, and that can have some security 
            implications for the application's data)
    -->
    <application
        android:theme="@style/sanome_theme"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.menus.SanoApplication" >



        <!-- LOGIN -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.login.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|adjustResize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_login" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>



        <!-- MENUS -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.nlrt.sanome.menus.MainMenuActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.nlrt.sanome.menus.SubMenuScreeningToolsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Now since this is my first time looking at this code, I actually had to refer to the AndroidManifest.xml to know which file launched the application. This file is auto-generated, so the library makes it realize that this is the application entry point of com.menu.SanoApplication is the previously mentioned library of android.app.Application. Is this correct? If not why?

The start up actually launches another file from a different package, I noted that in the manifest too. What is it that makes this  (com.login.LoginActivity) to be recognized launch file? That the  is the MAIN and LAUNCHER?

I am reviewing these files but I am lacking the knowledge to see how they are connected without the auto-generated file.

Thanks so much for any help that can be provided.

I am also looking for recommendations on a great beginner tutorial dealing with simple android application. Not one which details the steps to installation cause I got that done. Nor one that is helloworld - got that completed too. Does anyone have any better suggestions? Also one that references Netbeans IDE would be much appreciated.

Thanks Again for any help the can be provided.

**EDIT // SOLUTION**

The AndoridManifest.xml is not auto-generated. The link as provided by Lunchbox below states it very clearly. I was under the impression this file was created each time the Build action  is performed.

Comment: I use eclipse ADT to develop android apps. I used the following link to learn android development: http://www.mybringback.com/series/android-basics/ . It might be of some help to you, good luck

Comment: The AndroidManifest.xml is normally *not* auto-generated.  Yours is only because you used some sort of project creation wizard.

Comment: @ChrisStratton What I did was run build and voila it was there. Same as this little tutorial detailed. I did mention that I am using an Eclipse IDE. https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/dummy_guide_to_netbeans_android

Comment: Also @ChrisStratton your response doesn't help me with my question. It's like you've read to that point and stopped.

Comment: The problem is you haven't stated a clear question - your mention of libraries in the title is particularly spurious as they are not involved.  Do you want to know how the AndroidManifest.xml is created, or do you want to know how that influences what activity is launched?  For the record, it is normally created - or at least modified - by hand.  Anything else is a convenience shortcut not to be relied upon.

Comment: Oh I presumed it was. I will not take your word and look at it the way you're saying and I will remove the file and press build again to see if it appears again. :) If it doesn't than that answers my question... I made an error in presuming it was created for me.

Comment: @Lunchbox I love how the 2nd Tutorial says it right off the hop. **The “AndroidManifest.xml” will be the ‘boss’ file for our application. If we need our app to access the internet, send a text, access the user photo album, get the gps location, etc, we will have to ask permission within the Android Manifest, and we will also have to define all of our activities within the Manifest so our application know the Android structure."**

Comment: @ChrisStratton my previous post should read - **I will take your word for it...**

Comment: Yeah, the series teaches you the basics of almost everything. I followed it until number 50 or so, then I carried on by myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these lines:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.login.LoginActivity" ...>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You used intent-filter to tell Android that your LoginActivity should be shown to user on application startup: the MAIN action specifies the LoginActivity as an entry point of your application, and the LAUNCHER category tells android that this entry point should be listed in your Launcher's top level list of applications.

As for recommendations, I would highly suggest [The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development](http://commonsware.com/Android/). It is monumental.

Comment: Marking this as right. I was under the assumption that the file was auto-generated when I pressed build and that the intent filter was being created from an android library within that class.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this correct?

Not by my definition of "entry point".

> If not why?

An `Application` instance is not an "entry point". It is merely a singleton created as part of your process starting up, nothing more.

> What is it that makes this (com.login.LoginActivity) to be recognized launch file? That the is the MAIN and LAUNCHER?

If by "to be recognized launch file" you mean "to have an icon show up the home screen launcher", then yes, the `<intent-filter>` on that `<activity>` is causing this.

Comment: I get that, I did state that this file was auto-generated when I pushed the build in Netbeans IDE. That's how I figured this out. I am trying to understand what android libraries made this occur? I am working upon an already existing project. As I stated the library the library com.android.app.Application in the class SanoApplication is what sets this in the Manifest.xml. I need to understand what library is it that determines the LoginActivity is the Main Launch activity. I can read the xml, it's the android java libraries I need assistance with. Hope this clears-up my request.

Comment: @user2672744: "I am trying to understand what android libraries made this occur?" -- you are using the noun "libraries" where you should be using "classes". "I need to understand what library is it that determines the LoginActivity is the Main Launch activity" -- there is no Java class in your application that "determines the LoginActivity is the Main Launch activity". "the Main Launch activity" is determined by the `<intent-filter>` in the manifest file.

Comment: I think I may have err-ed in believing that the Manifest.xml was auto-generated by Netbeans IDE when doing a project Build.

Comment: @user2672744: The manifest is usually generated when a project is created, not when a project is compiled.